# Unable to download an excel file from express server

Tags: node.js, excel

I have express js running on my backend and I have a uploaded an excel file `(.xlsx)` on one of server folders and I am trying to download this file.

This is node middleware to do this task

```
records.get('/downloadSampleExcel', (req, res) => {
    const sampleExcel = `${__dirname}/../../upload/sampleExcel/data.xlsx`
    res.download(sampleExcel)
})
```

But the issue is when I use ajax request the file is not downloading and when I use `window.open(url)` a zip file is downloaded containing some strange files instead of my excel file.

What is the correct procedure to do??

Comment: I had kind of similar issue, the file path was correct, opening it in new tab was opening the file/downloading correctly. So the <a> target was set "_blank" to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using invalid path, use either [path.join()](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_join_paths) module to join path or absolute path

```
records.get('/downloadSampleExcel', (req, res) => {
    const path = require('path);
    const sampleExcel = path.join(__dirname, '../../upload/sampleExcel/data.xlsx');
    res.download(sampleExcel)
})
```

**Updated:**
set header before `res.download`

```
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=data.xlsx');
res.setHeader('Content-type', 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
res.download(sampleExcel)
```

Comment: i don't think that issue is with path because this issue is coming for my excel file only...when I tried to download `.json` and `.pdf` file from same path, they were downloaded correctly.